# How can I tell if Mercurial is Installed?

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial

I am using another developer's Ubuntu box and trying to tell if Mercurial is installed and working.

As @stew pointed out, I did the 'dpkg -l mercurial' command and got this:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                  Version               Description
+++-=====================-=====================-==========================================================
ii  mercurial             1.8-0ppa1~lucid1      scalable distributed version control system
agenadinik@slabrams-desktop:/usr/bin$ dpkg -l Mercurial
```

While it says the installation is recognized, it also gives some cryptic warning-like messages above.  It looks like it might be a bad installation.  Could anyone help me decipher those messages?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could see if the mercurial package were installed by checking if `dpkg -l mercurial` spits out a line with 'i' in the second column.  you could also try running `hg help` and see if you get a list of mercurial commands.

Comment: Thanks - I have some funky output to that command which I pasted as an answer because it allowed me to format the funky output to be more readable.  Are you able to interpret those messages?

Answer (score 1):

`which hg` returns 0 if the hg binary is found. In addition, if you don't need to do this in an automated script, it will print whether or not the binary was found into stdout.

**Edit:** Obviously this doesn't tell whether or not the *package* is properly installed, for which you should use the dpkg command – which you did.